# Top grouping performed collapse all by default in jqGrid 4.6.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a table with 2 grouping in jqGrid. The code I used is really similar with what I have in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjIlaVMsa9vusmfhgfL1?p=preview). The only difference is, the expand/collapse toggle works fine in my project.

However, for the first grouping I noticed that when I toggle to collapse, the first `#gridghead_0_0`, it will also set all elements inside that grouping and also other groupings to `'display:none'` (performing collapse all, and also hiding all the other grouping header). When I toggle `#gridghead_0_0` to expand, it will only set the elements inside that grouping to `'display:table-row'`. The collapse and expand of `#gridghead_0_1` (the second grouping) works perfectly fine without disturbing the first grouping.

This behaviour does not exist in jqGrid 4.8.0 however unfortunately I cannot upgrade to 4.8.0. Does anybody have the same behaviour?

Here's the DOM structure of my jqGrid elements:

this is my structure when everything is expanded (2 grouping headers):

[image]

this is my structure when first group is collapse (noticed that the second group also get display:none even though it shouldn't):

[image]

Please let me know if my question are not clear enough. I am trying to see if anybody else is having the same issue with version 4.6.0?

My workaround for this issue is modifying the onclick function for the (-) and (+) sign. But of course, this is a hack way. I am wondering if this a known issue?

Comment: first of all you should always include jQuery UI css in the demo. For example `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">`. The lines `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` are strictly recommended too. Now about your problem. Which **real disadvantages** you see from setting `display: table-row;` on the rows? Do you have some problems?

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the suggestions! and thank you for always replying fast. I see the problem with setting `display:table-row` to all rows. If some other grouping headers are closed, then I cannot set all rows to be `display:table-row`, I need to check the state of each grouping header which will be really messy. However, I see that the version in plunkr is working fine, which means it s not a bug with version 4.6.0... It's weird how it behaves differently in plunkr and my project, but I know it's not a problem with v4.6.0. Thanks again as always Oleg, sorry for novice questions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the reason why. This is because of I have `showSummaryOnHide = true` in my `groupingView` and this causes an issue. I can reproduce this problem in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZ8FbONwAd2QCzZv3WuU?p=preview) here.

https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/fe3747e03a43b1cf846b25feed43bc243766fa86

This is fixed in 4.7.0, and by taking out showSummaryOnHide it fixed my problem.